# Selenium get dynamic ID XPath

Tags: dynamic, xpath, selenium, count

I'm new on Selenium, new here and my english is not the best.

I'm using selenium with .NET ...

I have a HTML page like this but the number of the events are different:

```
<div id="eventContent" style="text-align: center;">
       <div class="event" id="event-8971062">
            <ul>
                <li ...></li>
                <li ...></li>
                <li ...></li>
            </ul>
       </div>                    
       <div class="event odd" id="event-9224880">
            <ul>
                <li ...></li>
                <li ...></li>
                <li ...></li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
</div>
```

I need to check all datas in the different divs but the count is dynamic and the (event)id is dynamic too. I'm trying to find out the count of the divs at first but this does'nt work. For that I try this:

```
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(...);
decimal count = selenium.GetXpathCount("//div[@id='eventContent']");
```

but this brings only 1 as result and not two for this example.

when I try:

```
Console.WriteLine(selenium.GetText("//div[@id='eventContent'][1]"));
```

it prints all divs, but when I do:

```
Console.WriteLine(selenium.GetText("//div[@id='eventContent'][1]/div"));
```

it prints only the first div and I do not understand why.
Could someone be so kind and give me an explaination of whats going on here and where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance
elur

Answer (score 6):

```
decimal count = selenium.GetXpathCount("//div[@id='eventContent']");
```

This will return the count of `div`s that have an `id` of `eventContent` - there is only one `div` like this, which is why you get a count of 1 (count variables are typically `int`s rather than `decimal`s, incidentally).

If you want the count of the *contained* `div`s, use

```
int count = selenium.GetXpathCount("//div[@id='eventContent']/div");
```

This will count the number of `div` *children* of the `div` with an `id` of `eventContent`. This should return 2, as desired.

As for your `GetText` examples, I think `GetText` will only return the text of the *first* node that the xpath argument selects. So with

```
selenium.GetText("//div[@id='eventContent'][1]")
```

you get the entire text of the *parent* `div`, which naturally contains all the child `div`s, but with

```
selenium.GetText("//div[@id='eventContent'][1]/div")
```

you get the text of only the *first* child `div`. This xpath selects all the child `div`s, but `GetText` operates on a single element only, I believe. If you want to examine the text of each child `div` in turn, you'll need to first get a count of the child `div`s, then use `for` loop to get each one in turn:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
{
    string childXpath = "//div[@id='eventContent']/div[" + i + "]";
    string eventText = selenium.GetText(childXpath);

    // Processing of eventText
}
```

A `for` loop and manual xpath processing are needed here (rather than the neater `foreach`), as I believe Selenium doesn't have a way of taking an xpath and returning a collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

tryed this but returns with 0. I solved this with a while expression where I check with isElementPresent like this:

```
int a = 1;
while (selenium.IsElementPresent("//div[@id='eventContent'][1]/div[" + a + "]"))
{
    // check data here
    a++;
}
```

seems to work so. thanks a lot for your help, 
best regards elur

Comment: I always forget that xpath indexes are 1-based not 0-based. Edited my example which should now do the same as your `while` loop.